# PHP child class doesn't have parent methods(possible configuration issue?)

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

EDIT: I'm adding a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhpv7.jpg) of the actual errors, as a proof that this is what happens.

[image: error message]

Note, that the $post_id and $id properties are undefined, because the parent `Y_CF` class has a magic `__get()` method, but again - it's not available in the child class.

---

I've had a bunch of issues already(including one, where PHP would pretty much just ignore a portion of an included file, even if I threw a bunch of random characters in there, which should cause a fatal error), but I'm finally down to a single issue:
I have two classes - a parent and a main class. 
The parent class is abstract and has a factory method that returns different child classes, based on parameters passed to it. 
The odd thing happens, with **one** of the child classes - it doesn't have the methods of the parent class. I'm posting only the relevant pieces of code

```
abstract class Y_CF {
    // even if "public", it doesn't work
    protected function parse_attributes( $attributes, $core_atts = array() ) {
        $this->__settings['attributes'] = wp_parse_args( $core_atts, $attributes );
    }
}

class Y_CF_Text extends Y_CF {
    public function __construct( $settings ) {
        parent::__construct( $settings );
        // This is false
        var_dump( method_exists( $this, 'parse_attributes' ) );

        $this->parse_attributes( $this->attributes, array(
            'id' => "Y_field_{$this->id}",
            'class' => esc_attr( 'yotta-text-input ' . $this->class ),
            'type' => ! empty( $this->attributes['type'] ) ? $this->attributes['type'] : 'text',
            'value' => $this->format_value( $this->value ),
            'name' => $this->gen_name(),
        ) );
    }
}
```

As you can see, my main class is `Y_CF` and I'm extending it with `Y_CF_Text`.

Note, that I've tried this code on my local server(ubuntu 14) and it works just fine(as it should).

I'm suspecting that the problem is somewhere in the server configuration, but I don't have any clue where.

What I did so far:

- Updated PHP to 5.5.12 ( the issue was happening with 5.3 as well )
- Disabled opcache
- Disabled memcached
- Restarted php, nginx and the whole server

All of those had no effect whatsoever.

I've also looked all over the internet and couldn't find anything that remotely mimics my situation.

Comment: Does the parent class hace a constructor? If not, get rid of the parent::__construct

Comment: Yes it does - I skipped it for readability. Note, that I have almost identical classes, that don't have this issue(each class takes care of a different type of form input).

Comment: Also the code **does work** on a different set-up, which is what leads me to think that it's a configuration issue(although, heck - what kind of configuration parameter disables class inheritance).

Comment: I don't think that what you're describing is possible. It's probably a bug or otherwise confusing behavior of `method_exists()`.

Comment: @Narf - that's what I thought too, but it is a fact. I get a fatal error saying that the method doesn't exist for the Y_CF_Text class...

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov It's surely not a configuration issue, and since you've already upgraded PHP, it's most likely a typo then ... I'm sure you've already checked, but try typing the method name again in both places - who knows, one of the characters could be in cyrilic or something ...

Comment: @Narf - I zipped all of the files and downloaded them to my computer. I set-up the virtual host, added an entry to my hosts file and everything was working fine. All of that without changing a single file(except for the database configuration), so I'm **sure** this is not a typo.

Comment: See my edit with the screenshot of the error as a proof that it really is not working.

Comment: If it is a server configuration issue and at some point it "ignored" part of you code it sounds likely that you should see something in the error logs. Can you look there? Also, can you var_export the object you believe to be of the child class?

Comment: Are both of these classes in the same source file?

Comment: @monocell - http://pastie.org/9202517 . There are references to other objects(a group object that holds all fields and a post object). I'll also look through the various logs on the server. Philip Adler - yes, they are in the same class.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov Are you exporting the object at the same place as you are using it? i.e. where you get the undefined notices?

Comment: @monocell - that's correct. I do the export directly above the place where I get the fatal error).

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have old code lying around and it includes a class of the same name as the one you are extending from, and that class lacks the method in question. Or you have another version of the child class or something like that. Can't think of anything else that might explain this.

Comment: I'm as stumped as you are... And your guesses shouldn't be the case, since I'm declaring the base class(I don't use `class_exists()` checks - I know, I'm bad for that) and I don't get a fatal error that the class already exists. Oh well, I'll keep trying and see what comes out of this...

Comment: Well, it might still happen if the correct code is not included. Which would explain why you could insert random characters into it and still not get a fatal error. (I also don't use class_exists, I think it's a horrible idiom)

Comment: But again - I have the completely same code over on my computer. This file is part of a WordPress plugin, so I have all of the files that run both times and yet it works just fine on my computer :( I've never seen such a problem before and it's driving me crazy

Comment: Yeah, so my guess was that you have all the same files on the server + a few more. Or that something causes the set of included files to be different between your server and locally. Regardless of what the problem turns out to be, It would be nice if you updated the question when you find it. I'm interested as well now. :/

Comment: Figured it out finally - incorrectly opened php tag and the server was configured to not accept short tags.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov: I think you should write this comment up with a little more detail as an answer, and accept it.

Comment: I tend to use the hammer towards this one: [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200640/367456) as it looks like a useful addition, however it is not an exact duplicate. The so far voted close reason looks fitting to me.

Comment: @hakre - Well, to me convenience in short tags is really not a reason to use them(I'm saying that regarding to some of the answers on that thread). Instead, using a good text editor with tab-triggered snippets  is **so** much better :) And I usually don't use them and use either `php{tab}`, or write them myself. I guess I wrote that myself and forgot the rest of the syntax :)

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov: FYI: I put this to discussion here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256048/367456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel very unlucky now :)

As a final resort, I started putting each of the classes in their own file. I got to the main class and I suddenly got the following error:

`<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in <b>/path/to/site/wp-content/plugins/yotta-util/lib/class-y-cf.php</b> on line <b>291</b><br />`

I was like WHAT?! So, I started going through the whole file and I finally pin-pointed the issue to a single method of the class. When I scrolled to the end of the method, I saw this:

```
{some javascript code}
</script>
<?
```

Notice the missing "php" part after the question mark - that's where all of those issues were coming from. A single opening tag mistyped.

Now, I don't usually use the short tags, but I guess most servers are already configured to handle them properly, so I never got a single problem. But the server I'm working on right now has them turned off.

Somehow, instead of triggering a fatal error or anything at all, this only caused the described puzzling mess.

So in the end - it was just a single typo that caused me to bang my head around for at least 6 hours.

Comment: It happens to the best of us.